# add table with border per cell in javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I know I can use html tags in Java docs. How do I add a table with borders for each cell? I want the cells to be align like a real table. I know the basic tags like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> cell 11 </td> <td> cell 21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> cell 12 </td> <td> cell 22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So how do I add borders and keep the table columns the same width?

Comment: `<table border="1"...` is not working?

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Putting @RP's comment in an answer, you can use the `border` attribute for `table` like this:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td> cell 11 </td> <td> cell 21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> cell 12 </td> <td> cell 22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The `border` attribute on `<table>` is no longer allowed in HTML5. Not sure it matters for Javadoc though.

Comment: JavaDoc 8 and 9 still default to HTML 4.01. JavaDoc 9 allows the use of HTML5 through a switch. I believe that JavaDoc 10 uses HTML5 by default

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work well with IntelliJ IDEA (2018.1.2)'s "quick documentation" JavaDoc viewer

Comment: It works but looks really ugly in IDEA's `Ctrl + Q` popup. Using `style="border-collapse: collapse;"` does not help.